# Jquery attr() - Mozilla behaves differently regarding the design (differenty font-family or font-size?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing the login form.

This is my view in CodeIgnitor:

```
<div id="login-form">
<?php
    echo heading('Login', 2);
    echo form_open('login/login_user');
    echo form_input('email', set_value('email', 'Email Address'));
    echo br();
    echo form_password('password', '', 'placeholder="Password" class="password"');
    echo br(2);
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');
    echo form_close();
    echo validation_errors('<p class="error">');
    ?>
</div>
```

With JavaScript I try to ensure the following functionality:

If a user clicks on the passoword field this field gets empty (ready for the user to write in his/her password). If the user does not write his/her password and clicks somewhere else, the passowrd field gets the placeholder Password again.

This is the JavaScript code that does it:

```
$(':password').focusin(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('placeholder') !== undefined){
        $(this).removeAttr('placeholder')
    }
});

$(':password.password').focusout(function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Password');
})
```

There is also a CSS that controls the color of the placeholder string (it makes it the same color as input field has it, in my case #999999).

```
input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
    display: block;
    padding: 3%;
    color: #999999;
    margin: 0 0 1% 0;
    width: 90%;
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #202020;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #999999;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #999999;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #999999;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #999999;  
}
```

**THE PROBLEM IS** that all this (the e-mail and passowrd field look the same) works fine in Chrome and IE10, but in Mozilla they look differently. The color is the same, but the letters of the password filed seem to be smaller or different font, therefore the two fields look different and its ugly.

Any idea why Mozilla behaves differently regarding the design (the JS functionality, remowing the placeholder and placing it again works fine)?

Thanks ...

... And here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m4i4/aCDxQ/1/).

Unfortunatelly I'm not able to set JS functionality here (so that when user clicks, the password fied would get empty. neverthelss, my problem is visible, if you check this DEMO out in Mozilla nad for example Chrome.

Comment: Can you provide a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net) or image of the problem?

Comment: why are you removing a placeholder with js - it will disappear automatically once the user starts typing

Comment: Rory McCrossan, here is [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m4i4/aCDxQ/1/). Please check it our in Mozilla and Chrome and you will se that the word E-mail address and Password have the same design in Chrome, but not in Mozilla.

Comment: Pete, I do not think so. On my computer, witjout JS, the input fields need to be deleted by the user (which is very annoying) and only then he/she can type in.

Comment: The placeholder will be removed when you start typing...If it does not, than you have other issues. The email has to be removed manually since for some reason you are not using a placeholder.

Comment: Thanks, a lot, but my main question is why in Mozilla the word "Passowrd" looks lighter than the word "Email Address", while in for example Chrome, both words look the same. Please check out the DEMO.

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks, a lot, but my main question is why in Mozilla the word "Passowrd" looks lighter than the word "Email Address", while in for example Chrome, both words look the same. Please check out the DEMO

Because email is set with value and the password is a placeholder.

```
    <input 
        type="text" 
        name="email" 
        value="Email Address"/>  <--------- Value
    <input 
        type="password" 
        name="password" 
        value=""         
        placeholder="Password" <--------- Placeholder
        class="password"/>
```

The email's text color should be the default color of the textbox.

Comment: I see, yes. Good observation. Thanks! But why Chrome can handle this (display Email Address and Password in exactly the same style), while Mozilla has trouble (Password seems smaller than Email Address). Any idea?

Comment: Because placeholder has different defaults. Why are you not using placeholder in email address in the first place? Wouldn't that solve your problems?

Comment: It probably would ... But for the email addres I need the value. If a user types in his/her e-mail and password and lets say, password is wrong, then I want my login system to keep/remember the email. Otherwise the user would need to type it in again just because he/she was wrong with the password.

Comment: So you set the value with the email address, the placeholder will NOT show up. Do you not understand how a placeholder works? `<input placeholder="Email Address" value="User's value" />` And you are breaking a rule, a placeholder should not be used as a replacement of a label element.

Comment: Now I have made a change of color in CSS: ::-moz-placeholder, :-moz-placeholder, input [type=text], input [type=password] now have color:red. And strangly in Mozilla they both look red (a proof that Mozilla take the color of ::-moz-placeholder and :-moz-placeholder), but Password is not as bright as Email Address. In Chrome and IE10, they both look exactly the same. You can check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aCDxQ/4/).

Comment: I'm using CodeIgnitor's <?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', 'Email Address'));?> so it will be quite a task for me to put a placeholder in here. But I will.

Comment: POSSIBLE SOLUTION: I've done one extremly stupid trick, but it works prety good (at least with the colors I'm using) ::-moz-placeholder, :-moz-placeholder {color:white}. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m4i4/aCDxQ/6/)